# how to fix Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') in JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have this error in my terminal:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I'm trying to test the call to an API, but the error appears.

my code:

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Component } = require('discord.js');
function makeid(length) {
var result = '';
var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
var charactersLength = characters.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
        charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('script')
    .setDescription('รับสคริป'),
execute: async (interaction, con, log, client, config) => {
        log(`[LOG Command] ${interaction.user.username}, use command getscript`, "green")
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');

    const menu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("SELRCTION")
        .addOptions(
            { label: "BloxFruit", description: "script BloxFruit ", value: "BF", emoji: ""},
            { label: "City Thiland", description: "script City Thiland 2", value: "CTTH", emoji: ""},
        ),
    );
       
    /*interaction.relpy({ content: "You Select ", ephemeral: true, components: {menu}});*/
    await con.query(`SELECT userkey, discord_id,Blacklisted FROM bloxfruit Where discord_id = '${interaction.user.id}'`, async function(err, results, fields) {
    if(!results[0]) {
        await interaction.reply({ 
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#FF0000")
                .setTitle('**"WET HUB" | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                .setDescription("คุณไม่มีไวริสนะคะ กรุณาก่อนใช้ด้วยค่ะ")
                .setTimestamp()
            ],
            ephemeral: true
        })
    } else {
     if(results[0].Blacklisted == "True") {
        await interaction.reply({ 
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#FF0000")
                .setTitle('**WET HUB | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                .setDescription("คุณอยู่ในบัญชีดำนะคะ")
                .setTimestamp()
            ],
            ephemeral: true
        })
     } else {
        let key = results[0].userkey
        let discord_id = results[0].discord_id
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "You Select",
            ephemeral: true,
            components: [menu],
        })
        const value = interaction.values[0];
        switch (value) {
            case "BF":
                {
                await interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [
                    new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor("00FF46")
                    .setTitle('**WET HUB | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                    .setDescription('```lua\ngetgenv().Key = "'+ key + '"\ngetgenv().DiscordId = "'+ discord_id + '"\nloadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Galiverking/CheckPointWT/main/check-lua.lua"))()```')
                    .setTimestamp()
                ], 
                ephemeral: true
            });
                }
                break;
            case "CTTH":
                {
                await interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [
                    new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor("00FF46")
                    .setTitle('**WET HUB | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                    .setDescription('```lua\ngetgenv().Key = "'+ key + '"\ngetgenv().DiscordId = "'+ discord_id + '"\nloadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Galiverking/CheckPointWT/main/check-lua.lua"))()```')
                    .setTimestamp()
                ], 
                ephemeral: true
            });
                }
                break;

                default:
                    break;
        }
    };
     }
  })
}
````

}

It can only choose an answer. but does not send data.
[image]
I've tried to fix it but I can't fix it.
I think there's a mistake here.
 `const value = interaction.values[0];`
What have I done wrong?
please help me

Comment: Provide us the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you did not handle error for results

```
 await con.query(`SELECT userkey, discord_id,Blacklisted FROM bloxfruit Where discord_id = '${interaction.user.id}'`, async function(err, results, fields) {
if(!results || results.length ===0) {
 //Handle Error 
 console.log('Results is empty');

  if (!err) {
      return '';
    } else if (err instanceof Error) {
      return errors.fullStack(err);
    } else {
      return JSON.stringify(err);
    }

}
    if(!results[0]) {
```